# What can cause [DataDirect][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver]Connection refused.?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, odbc

The Title speaks for itself.

We have this error message on the client side of the application.
The devs suspect a problem on the database.
The alert log on the database shows no errors at all.
The only events I have are the regular archived logs shipping to the standby database.

I was suspecting processes and sessions parameters to be a bit too low, but currently

select count(*) from v$process shows 36 process running. Granted this is not peak time, but I would need to have ora-00020 in my alert log anyway should I hit this threshold...

What else could be happening?

Comment: Do the steps [here](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21251104) help?

Comment: It'll be a network problem/firewall issue if other clients can connect to the database. Can you tnsping/ping/traceroute to the database server from the client?